# looking for public dataset for stock market

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, visualization, web-scraping

I want to do some modelling and data visualization on historical stock data, including price, volume, financials, etc. Is there an public dataset available for stock price history? I looked at a few, but either they have a high cost, or not sure they would be reliable. Free would be preferred, also established and reliable. If not, what are some good options for collecting the data myself? Maybe web scraping, or public api's etc.

Comment: Yahoo Finance also has a nice API for stock market data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the kaggle stock dataset.

https://www.kaggle.com/borismarjanovic/price-volume-data-for-all-us-stocks-etfs

This questions are normally done in OpenData stack exchange.

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to opendata, I look for public data often, hopefully this stack site will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am well aware that this is an old post, however for anybody with similar problems I would like to mention AlphaVantage.

AlphaVantage (https://www.alphavantage.co/) offers a free stock data API with a lot of request flags. All you need is an account and you're good to go. I have personally used AlphaVantage and have not had any problems.